# css how to show horizontal scrollbar to overflow the content of a div in a resizable panel

Tags: css, reactjs, resize

I have downloaded a Reactjs component to hold several panels (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-panelgroup) and resize them, but I need the content of the resizable panel to stretch when the container is bigger than its maxwidth and show a scrollbar when its container is shorter.

[image: example],

but I am getting this instead:

[image: result]

this is what I have:

```
<PanelGroup
        direction="row"
        spacing={5}
        panelWidths={[
          { size: 500, minSize: 125, resize: 'dynamic' },
          { size: 500, minSize: 125, resize: 'dynamic' },
          { minSize: 200, resize: 'stretch' }
        ]}
      >
        <div><div style={{ width: `${first}px`, minWidth: `${Math.trunc(first/4)}px`, overflow: 'auto'}}>panel sasasa asa fa fdd dfds af dasfds  df dfas sf df sdafds1</div></div>
        <div>paneldsfd fsd sdfsd fsdf sdfds fasf  2</div>
        <div>panelsdaf sdfdasfsfs sdf sd 3</div>
      </PanelGroup>
```

What I need is not to wrap the content, but to scroll the container. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried setting a `minWidth`?

Comment: yes, same result